# Aborting SSE request in ASP.NET Core gracefully

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, server-sent-events

I am implementing SSE in middleware.

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    var request = context.Request;

    if (request.Headers.ContainsKey("Accept") && request.Headers["Accept"].Equals("text/event-stream"))
    {
        try
        {
            // do something that can throw exception

            context.Response.Headers["Content-Type"] = "text/event-stream";
            await context.Response.Body.FlushAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            context.Abort();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

When exception occurs and context is aborted, I always get this error

```
ProcessRequestAsync
System.InvalidOperationException: Headers already sent.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.Response.CheckResponseStarted()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.Response.set_CacheTtl(Nullable`1 value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.FeatureContext.ConsiderEnablingResponseCache()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.FeatureContext.<OnResponseStart>d__131.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.MessagePump.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.MessagePump.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
```

Here is how I register the middleware in `Startip.cs`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseSseMiddleware<SseMiddleware>();
    app.UseResponseCompression();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUi3();
}
```

How can I gracefully aborting the context without getting that exception?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please tell me when you will call this middleware? Please share your startup.cs codes.

Comment: @BrandoZhang I registered the middleware on startup normally `app.UseSseMiddleware<SseMiddleware>();` . And the middleware will be called on UI mount event.

Comment: The SseMIddleware is your customer middleware, we need to know when you called this middleware and what is this SSEmiddelware. If you just create a custom middleware it will not throw this error.   Besides, could you please tell me what's UI mount event?

Comment: SSE is server-sent events. This is how I call it from UI: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Comment: Could you please share the startup.cs Configure method related codes?

Comment: I put the `Configure` method in the question.